# Calculate size of folders inside S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket named "mybuckettest" in my AWS account. Inside this bucket I have multiple folders like "Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3". Inside each of these folders, I have sub folders as well. It can be simulated as shown below:

```
mybuckettest
    Folder1
        subfolder1
             content1
             content2
             content3
             content4
        subfolder2
             content1
    Folder2
        subfolder1
    Folder3
        subfolder1
             content1
             content2
```

I am trying to figure out the size of each folders "Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3" separately. Is there any specific way to do this using API? I mean I am trying to build an application through which I want to do this. Does anyone has an idea on this? My application language is Python-Django.

Answer (score 1):

```
Folder1
    subfolder1
         content1
```

is just on key named `Folder1/subfolder1/content1`.
If you know all keys, then just add their all `Content-Length` by [GET Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html); else you can get all keys's info in same `prefix(eg: Folder1)` by [GET Bucket (List Objects) Version 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) with `prefix` in `Request`, then add  their all `Size`.

Comment: Do you mean to say that we should list all the objects & sub folders inside Folder1 and then calculate the total size of all objects.?

Comment: No, if you want to calculate all keys's size prefixed with `Folder1`, you can use `GET /?list-type=2&max-keys=3&prefix=Folder1` to get maxium 3 keys that prefix with `Folder1`, just like `Example 2: Listing Keys Using the max-keys, prefix, and start-after Parameters` in [GET Bucket (List Objects) Version 2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html)`

Comment: Alright.. Let me check then.. I will accept the answer once I get the intended result. Else I will come up with any doubt I have. Thanks for now :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use [Amazon S3 Storage Inventory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily CSV file of the contents of your Amazon S3 buckets.

You could then parse this file with a simple Python script rather than calling making API List calls.